# giving unique id to each element and accessing them using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to print the realtime output based on user input for a search. so im trying to add the title of each result to a div element of a certain width and height. I want to limit the entries of each div element to 8. so for different search, the number of divs to be displayed will vary. 
Im using the below code, since #test is not unique, all output title will be displayed in a single div instead of divs containing 8 titles each..I want to know hw we cn create a div with unique id and use the jquery function to add title to these unique divs..how do i do that?

```
for(var count5=0;count5

{ $(".panel1").append('<div id="test"  style="width:200px; height:120px; background-color:#000000; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; color:#ffffff;"></div>');

    for(count4=num; count4<num1; ++count4)
    {   
             $("#test").append(prsnArray[count4].term + '<br>');
    }
num=num+8
num1=num1+8}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending the terms in your person array to the div with id 'test'(which is not unique as it should be), append those to the newly created div.

```
 var $newDiv = $('<div style="width:200px; height:120px; background-color:#000000; float:left; margin-left:10px; margin-top:10px; color:#ffffff;"></div>') ; 
 $(".panel1").append($newDiv);

 for(count4=num; count4<num1; ++count4){   
    $newDiv.append(prsnArray[count4].term + '<br>');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist off, fix your markup! `<br>` looks ugly you should use lists or definition lists.

for the div's id you could use a global variable as a counter and concaternate that with an id such as

```
myvar++;
$('#test'+myvar).doSth(...)
```

or you could add a class to the div

```
<div id="test1" class="mydivs"> ... </div>
```

and then

```
var newid = $('.mydivs').length + 1;
while($('#test'+newid).length > 0){newid++;}
```